# Is there a way to fix the teardrops sliders being above the text?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, mobile, flutter-layout

I'm having a weird problem with the sliders of a selected text in a textfield as in the image below, it's only occurring in this screen and not in the rest

[The problem image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JCplq.png)

and this is the code of the Textfield:

```
                           Row(
                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                            children: [
                                    Text(
                                    'Maiden Name :',
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                        fontSize: 16, color: Colors.grey.shade700),
                                     ),
                                    Flexible(
                                    child: SizedBox(
                                      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 2,
                                      height: 30,
                                      child: TextField(
                                        cursorColor: Colors.grey.shade700,
                                        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16),
                                        decoration: new InputDecoration(
                                          hintText:
                                              'As per your official documents',
                                          hintStyle: TextStyle(
                                              color: Colors.grey.shade900,
                                              fontSize: 10,
                                              fontStyle: FontStyle.italic),
                                          isDense: true,
                                          filled: true,
                                          fillColor: Colors.white,
        
                                          border: OutlineInputBorder(
                                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),
                                            borderSide: BorderSide(),
                                          ),
                                          focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),
                                            borderSide: BorderSide(),
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                        controller: familyNameController,
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                 ],
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a solution for the problem,

fixed by adding

```
contentPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 5),
```

to the InputDecoration in the textfield and by removing Flexible widget, so it becomes like this:

```
Container(
                                    width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 2,
                                    height: 30,
                                    child: TextField(
                                            cursorColor: Colors.grey.shade700,
                                            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                            style:
                                                TextStyle(fontSize: 16),
                                            textAlignVertical: TextAlignVertical.center,
                                            decoration: new InputDecoration(
                                              hintText:
                                                  'As per your official documents',
                                              hintStyle: TextStyle(
                                                  color: Colors.grey.shade900,
                                                  fontSize: 10,
                                                  fontStyle: FontStyle.italic),
                                              isDense: true,

                                              //focusColor: Colors.black,
                                              filled: true,
                                              fillColor: Colors.white,
                                              contentPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 5),

                                              border: OutlineInputBorder(
                                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),
                                                borderSide: BorderSide(),
                                              ),
                                              focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),
                                                borderSide: BorderSide(),
                                              ),
                                            ),
                                            controller: surnameController,
                                          ),
                                  ),
```